# How to convert timestamp value to specific time format using react native?

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native

In my scenario, I need to convert `timestamp` value to specific time format in react native. I tired below code but can't able to achieve exact formate output. How to achieve it?

```
 var dateTime = new Date(23456789 * 1000);
    this.setState({DateTime:('0' + dateTime.getUTCDate()).slice(-2) +
            '/' + ('0' + dateTime.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2) +
            '/' + dateTime.getUTCFullYear() +
            '' + ('0' + dateTime.getUTCHours()).slice(-2)
        });
```

Exact output expecting : `Wed, 2/01/2000 - 1.10 AM`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can convert using the following

```
 var timestemp = new Date( 23456789000 );
var formatted = timestemp.format("dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss");
```

you can get day, date, year and month like this

```
  var day = timestemp.getDay();
  var date = timestemp.getDate();
  var month = timestemp.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = timestemp.getFullYear();
```

**Update**

```
var t = new Date(23456789000);
var formatted = ('0' + t.getDate()).slice(-2) 
    + '/' + ('0' + t.getMonth()).slice(-2)
    + '/' + (t.getFullYear())
    + ' ' + ('0' + t.getHours()).slice(-2);
```

Output

```
29/08/1970 17
```

**Update:**

```
    var t = new Date(1589343013000);
var hours = t.getHours();
var minutes = t.getMinutes();
var newformat = t.getHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';  

// Find current hour in AM-PM Format 
hours = hours % 12;  

// To display "0" as "12" 
hours = hours ? hours : 12;  
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes; 
var formatted = 
    (t.toString().split(' ')[0]) 
    + ', ' +('0' + t.getDate()).slice(-2) 
    + '/' + ('0' + (t.getMonth() + 1) ).slice(-2)
    + '/' + (t.getFullYear())
    + ' - ' + ('0' + t.getHours()).slice(-2)
    + ':' + ('0' + t.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
    + ' ' + newformat;
```

Output :

```
Wed, 13/05/2020 - 09:40 AM
```

Comment: I can't able to get Day

Comment: is there any node module like Moment?

Comment: @questanswer : Check my updated answer. it's working fine.

Comment: @questanswer : Did you get a chance to check my updated answer.?

Comment: I need to get exact format Wed, 2/01/2000 - 1.10 AM

Answer (score 0):

I tried this {`${new Date(23456789000).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')}`}, got 29/09/1970 in output.
Instead of timestamp, I used my date value fetched from database e.g. {`${new Date(myobject.myfield).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')}`} that also worked, I've defined inteface in React that matches my db object.